# Meaning of index 0 of matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

In R (My version is 4.2.2), I know that the index start from one.

There is a matrix x

```
x <- matrix(1:6, 2, 3)
```

Then subsetting above the dimension of the matrix produces an error, obviously.

```
x[2, 4]

Error in x[2, 4] : subscript out of bounds
```

However, index 0 does not.

```
x[2, 0]

integer(0)
```

I wonder what is the meaning of index 0 in matrix in R.

Answer (score 2):

For numeric `i` and `j`, `x[i, j]` is equivalent to:

```r
ii <- trunc(i)
jj <- trunc(j)
x[ii[ii != 0], jj[jj != 0]]
```

Hence indices greater than -1 and less than 1 (including 0) are simply ignored; they don't "mean" anything.

That implies that:

- `x[c(1, 0), c(0, 1)]` is equivalent to `x[1, 1]`.
- `x[2, 0]` is equivalent to `x[2, numeric(0)]`.

These are length-1 and length-0 vectors rather than 1-by-1 and 1-by-0 matrices because dimensions are dropped by default in the `m`-by-1 and 1-by-`n` cases (see `?Extract`).

Answer (score 2):

I really recommend reading the [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html). Some relevant quotes:

> A special case is the zero index, which has null effects: x[0] is an
> empty vector and otherwise including zeros among positive or negative
> indices has the same effect as if they were omitted.

> Subsetting multi-dimensional structures generally follows the same
> rules as single-dimensional indexing for each index variable